# Calculate time between startdate and enddate and subtracting days that have no worktime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My goal is to check if an email is answered within 24 hours during workdays. de definition of a workday is if there is time registered in another table. this because we sometimes work on a Saturday or a Sunday or to exclude holidays. I made a view from that table that gives a 1 if the date has worktime or a 0 if there is no worktime registered.

| DateWorked | HasWorked |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-04-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-04-03 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2021-04-04 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2021-04-05 00:00:00.000 | 1 |

So for example a few situations:

**1.** MailIncoming: 2021-04-01 16:30:00, MailAnswering: 2021-04-02 14:00:00

This one is easy, I don't have to subtract anything and the mail is answered within 24 hours.

**2.** MailIncoming: 2021-04-01 09:30:00, MailAnswering: 2021-04-03 14:00:00

This one is also easy, I don't have to subtract anything and the mail is not answered within 24 hours.

**3.** MailIncoming: 2021-04-03 12:30:00, MailAnswering: 2021-04-05 10:00:00

There is 1 day where no one has worked, so I need to subtract 1 whole day from the total time, and in that case the email is answered within 24 hours during workdays.

**4.** MailIncoming: 2021-04-04 11:00:00, MailAnswering: 2021-04-05 18:00:00

The remaining 13 hours from 04 do not count toward the '24 hours during workdays' so the email is answered within 24 during workdays.

Also, there can be multiple dates with zero after each other.

So the outcome I'm looking for is:

| MailIncoming | MailAnswering | TotalTime | TotalTimeWithoutDaysNotWorked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-04 11:00:00.000 | 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 | 31 | 18 |

How can I calculate this last column? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Your question mentions two tables.  And I'm not even sure that the sample data is really from one of them.

Comment: You would need the calendar table to have start and end times of working hours for each day

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a column HasNotWorked, so the tables are

```
create table WorkingDay(DateWorked Date, HasNotWorked int);
create table MailIncoming(MailIncoming DateTime, MailAnswering DateTime);
```

and the rows

```
insert into WorkingDay values('2021-04-01', 0);
insert into WorkingDay values('2021-04-02', 0);
insert into WorkingDay values('2021-04-03', 0);
insert into WorkingDay values('2021-04-04', 1);
insert into WorkingDay values('2021-04-05', 0);
insert into WorkingDay values('2021-04-06', 0);

insert into MailIncoming values('2021-04-04 11:00:00.000', '2021-04-06 18:00:00.000');
```

I want calculate the start date. If is in working day, we must consider the hour of the mail, else the first working day with

```
case when 
        (select HasNotWorked from WorkingDay where DateWorked = convert(date, MailIncoming)) = 1 then 
        (select min(DateWorked) from WorkingDay where DateWorked > MailIncoming and HasNotWorked = 0)
      else MailIncoming end as startDate
```

and discard the day that are not working day

```
((select sum(HasNotWorked) from WorkingDay where DateWorked between convert(date, startDate) 
  and convert(date, MailAnswering)
) * 24) as numNotWorkingDay
```

so the query could be

```
select startDate, MailAnswering, MailIncoming, hour, numNotWorkingDay, hour - numNotWorkingDay hourWitoutWorkingDay
from (
  select
    MailAnswering, startDate, MailIncoming,
    DateDiff("hh", startDate, MailAnswering) hour, 
    ((select sum(HasNotWorked) from WorkingDay where DateWorked between convert(date, startDate) 
      and convert(date, MailAnswering)
    ) * 24) as numNotWorkingDay 

  from (
    select *,
      case when 
        (select HasNotWorked from WorkingDay where DateWorked = convert(date, MailIncoming)) = 1 then 
        (select min(DateWorked) from WorkingDay where DateWorked > MailIncoming and HasNotWorked = 0)
      else MailIncoming end as startDate  
    from MailIncoming) as startCalc
) as calcTable;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00975/28)

Answer (score 0):

The query needs a way to generate calculated dates between MailIncoming and MailAnswering so there can be a `LEFT JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`) to the WorkingDay table.  In this case the query uses [dbo.fnTally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) which is known to be a fast and efficient way to generate rows.

tables

```
drop table if exists #WorkingDay;
go
create table #WorkingDay(
    DateWorked        Date,
    HasNotWorked      int);

drop table if exists #MailIncoming;
go
create table #MailIncoming(
    MailIncoming      DateTime,
    MailAnswering     DateTime);


insert into #WorkingDay values
('2021-04-01', 0),
('2021-04-02', 0),
('2021-04-03', 0),
('2021-04-04', 1),
('2021-04-05', 0),
('2021-04-06', 0);

insert into #MailIncoming values
('2021-04-01 16:30:00', '2021-04-02 14:00:00'),
('2021-04-01 09:30:00', '2021-04-03 14:00:00'),
('2021-04-03 12:30:00', '2021-04-05 10:00:00'),
('2021-04-04 11:00:00', '2021-04-05 18:00:00');
```

dbo.fnTally

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
    Jeff Moden Script on SSC: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

query

```
select mi.MailIncoming, mi.MailAnswering,
        avg(datediff(hour, MailIncoming, MailAnswering)) hrs_to_ans,
        sum(case when w.HasNotWorked=1 and 
                        v.calc_dt > mi_dt.inc_dt and 
                        v.calc_dt < mi_dt.ans_dt
                then -24
                when w.HasNotWorked=1 
                then datediff(hour, dateadd(day, 1, mi_dt.inc_dt), mi.MailIncoming)
            else 0 end) hrs_to_sub
from #MailIncoming mi
        cross apply (values (cast(MailIncoming as date), 
                            cast(MailAnswering as date))) mi_dt(inc_dt, ans_dt)
        cross apply dbo.fnTally(0, datediff(day, mi.MailIncoming, mi.MailAnswering)) fn
        cross apply (values (dateadd(day, fn.n, mi_dt.inc_dt))) v(calc_dt)
        left join #WorkingDay w on v.calc_dt=w.DateWorked
group by mi.MailIncoming, mi.MailAnswering
order by mi.MailIncoming;
```

```
MailIncoming            MailAnswering           hrs_to_ans  hrs_to_sub
2021-04-01 09:30:00.000 2021-04-03 14:00:00.000 53          0
2021-04-01 16:30:00.000 2021-04-02 14:00:00.000 22          0
2021-04-03 12:30:00.000 2021-04-05 10:00:00.000 46          -24
2021-04-04 11:00:00.000 2021-04-05 18:00:00.000 31          -13
```